# failed to compress javascript files using yuicompressor

Tags: java, maven, ant, yui-compressor

I have an ant file which contains a task to compress certain js files. I am using `yui compressor` to compress my files. So I have defined the taskdef

```
<taskdef resource="yuicompressor.tasks" classpath="lib/yuicompressor-taskdef-1.0.jar;lib/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar" />
```

and this is how I am using yui compressor ant task

```
<yuicompressor todir="./js/" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="./js/" 
        includes="**/*.js"> 
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*.js" />
</yuicompressor>
```

When I run this `ant` file directly it works fine, that is all js files get compressed.

But when I run this ant file from `pom.xml` then it shows

```
Failed to compress files file_name.js
```

This is my execution task in pom.xml

```
<execution>
    <id>default</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <tstamp />
            <ant antfile="build.xml" />
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: That's a pretty old version of yuicompressor; also, it would probably be useful to include a link to the JS source in question. Note that a lot of modern JS isn't valid EcmaScript 3 (which is officially the only dialect supported by yuicompressor so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was using the relative path in `yuicompressor`

```
<yuicompressor todir="./js/" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="./js/" 
        includes="**/*.js"> 
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*.js" />
</yuicompressor>
```

I updated to

```
<yuicompressor todir="${basedir}/js/" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/js/" 
        includes="**/*.js"> 
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*.js" />
</yuicompressor>
```

And working perfectly fine!!